# Oscillation of a function over a bounded open interval

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

I came across this definition when studying about discontinuous functions on $R^1$

> Let *f*:$R^1$->$R^1$.If J is any bounded open interval in $R^1$, we define $\omega$[*f*;J] (called the oscillation of *f* over J) as
>
> $\omega$[*f*;J]= $l.u.b_{x\in J}$ *f*(x)- $g.l.b_{x\in J}$ *f*(x).

I am not able to exactly understand what does this mean and in what is it related to discontinuity.
Also what is meant by oscillation of *f* at a point a.

**If possible please explain with an example for the same**

Answer (score 2):

Consider a continuous function at $a$ $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , we have that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$, now let $J=(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon>0$, the limit condition can be rewritten as $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \omega(f,J)=0  $$
Why? Because $\omega(f,J)=\text{lub}\{f(x)\mid a-\epsilon<x<a+\epsilon\}-\text{glb}\{f(x)\mid a-\epsilon<x<a+\epsilon\}$ should vanish as $\epsilon$ get smaller. If $f$ was not continuous, then $\omega(f,J)$ will not go to zero, that is why it is related to discontinuity. Take for example a function $f(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$. Clearly there is a discontinuity at $0$, of how much? well, $\omega$ will tell us. $$\omega (f,(-1,1))=1 $$
Hope it helps.